# How to redirect to a separate url from angular application using nginx

Tags: angular, nginx, url-routing

I have two separate angular applications deployed at different urls but I want to navigate to the 2nd application when user click a link from the 1st application with url https://fisrturl.com/2ndapp to the 2nd app deployed url https://2ndurl.com.